# When using flask, what is the best way to remembering parameters while paginating?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, query-string

Say that I have a results page that has several filters. The filters are passed to flask as URL parameters. But once I press Next Page, this will be forgotten. What is the best way to keep these parameters as you go from page to page?

I'm sure javascript frameworks exist to do this, but I'd rather not use javascript frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're rendering HTML and not JSON (which it seems like you are from the tag), why not just add the filter query parameters from the request into the rendered page?

For example, something like this:

Python:

```
@app.route('/search')
def search():
    page_no = request.args.get('page_no')
    color = request.args.get('color')
    brand = request.args.get('brand')
    # TODO: Generate your results here..
    return render_template('results.html', results=results, page_no=page_no, brand=brand color=color)
```

Template:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('search', page_no=str(page_no - 1), brand=brand, color=color) }}">Prev</a>
<a href="{{ url_for('search', page_no=str(page_no + 1), brand=brand, color=color) }}">Next</a>
```

This is a minimal example. You'll also want to handle special cases like not rendering a "previous" link on the first page. Probably also some validation on the input parameters. But it demonstrates how to maintain the filter parameters in the link URL.

Depending on how many filter parameters you have, you could also consider DRYing it up something like this:

Python:

```
FILTER_PARAM_NAMES = ['keyword', 'date', 'foo', 'bar']
# ...
def search():
    filter_params = {f: request.args.get(f) for f in FILTER_PARAM_NAMES}
    # ...
    return render_template('results.html', results=results, **filter_params)
```

Template:

```
url_for('search', page_no=page_no, **filter_params)
```

Comment: So, supposing we pick the "filter_str", then how would this string be generated by the HTML? For example if I have a dropdown to pick a filter color, that could get a "color=blue" GET parameter. But I wanted to use "filter_str=color:blue,brand:nike", how would HTML generate this? I guess that using the "render_template **filter_params" alternative this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Yes, using multiple parameters is probably better than cramming them into a single filter_str param. I'll update the example using your parameter names.

Comment: Ok so in that case how would the code `url_for color=yellow` etc be generated? If you don't a priori the number of filters (since most of the times some of the filters won't be used) then how do you deal with that?

Comment: If your parameters are generated by an HTML form, but you don't know the number of filters which the user will supply, the unused parameters will probably be empty strings. In that case, simply ignore empty parameters in your code which generates the results. Try it and see..